# Install mcrypt extension on mac

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

How can I install the Mcrypt PHP extension?

```
MAMP PHP Version: 7.3.1
OS: MacOS Mojave
Script: Laravel v4.2.8
```

`php -m | grep mcrypt` does not output nothing

Comment: `sudo pecl install mcrypt`, most likely. You may run into all sorts of trouble running Laravel 4 on PHP 7, though.

Comment: You might want to try your luck with https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP, find the directory of the PHP version you have enabled:

```
      cat /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf \
            | grep php | grep -i LoadModule | head -n1 \
            | sed -e 's/^[^\/]*\/\(.*\)\/mod.*/\/\1/'
```

Do a search, in that folder to determine if you have a loadable mcrypt version for the PHP that you have installed:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10
find . | grep mcrypt\.so
```

It should output something similar to:

```
./lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so
```

If not, go up a directory, and do a search again:

```
cd ..
find . | grep mcrypt\.so
```

and switch to a version of PHP (newer then 5.5) that has the module:

```
./php5.5.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so
./php7.0.32/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mcrypt.so
./php7.1.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so
```

Once switched, find this file, and edit it:

```
      cat /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf \
            | grep php | grep -i LoadModule | head -n1 \
            | sed -e 's/^[^\/]*\/\(.*\)\/mod.*/\/\1\/conf\/php.ini/'
```

You will need to add the following line:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Comment: directory : /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.1

Comment: find | grep mcrypt\.so
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: Ah, sorry, I use `gnufind`, the correct command is `find . | grep mcrypt\.so` @blacko